# How to iterate over a Map in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, dictionary, mutablemap

So I am new to Kotlin and I am wondering what's the standard way of iterating a Map. I have tried different ways and all of them seem to work, but I don't know if there's one better than the rest or there are some differences that I am not aware of.

```
    var mutMap = mutableMapOf("one" to 1, "two" to 2, "tree" to 3, "four" to 4, "five" to 5)

    mutMap.forEach { entry -> println(entry) }

    mutMap.iterator().forEach { entry -> println(entry) }

    mutMap.entries.forEach { entry -> println(entry) }

    mutMap.entries.iterator().forEach { entry -> println(entry) }

    for (entry in mutMap) { println(entry) }

    for (entry in mutMap.entries) { println(entry) }

    for (entry in mutMap.iterator()) { println(entry) }

    for (entry in mutMap.entries.iterator()) { println(entry) }
```

Also, if I wanted to also delete an entry while iterating over them, none of them would work, right?

Comment: For your first question study the docs on Collections: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collections-overview.html. For the second question: you can use _remove_, see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-write.html#removing-elements, but the "Kotlin"-way to do it would probably be to not use a MutableMap, but a Map, which is immutable, and then use _filter_ https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-filtering.html

Comment: I haven't studied the code, but I expect that all the different variations end up doing approximately the same thing. So go with the simplest: `for (entry in mutMap)` or `mutMap.forEach { entry ->`, depending on your preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you browse through Kotlin's [Collections](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/) package there is a whoooole lot of stuff you can use, yeah! Lots of different functions that let you drill down into specific pieces of data (like keys or values vs entries, or providing indices) or getting specific behaviour as you process a collection.

The examples you've given are all basically the same thing though. [Here's the page for all the `forEach` functions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html) on the various types of collections:

```
inline fun <T> Array<out T>.forEach(action: (T) -> Unit)
(source)

// a bunch of other Kotlin-specific Array types

inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEach(action: (T) -> Unit)
```

```
inline fun <K, V> Map<out K, V>.forEach(
    action: (Entry<K, V>) -> Unit)
```

```
inline fun <T> Iterator<T>.forEach(operation: (T) -> Unit)
```

And here's the source code for those (there's a source link under every function's main page, useful to know about! You can see exactly how they work)

```
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEach(action: (T) -> Unit): Unit {
    for (element in this) action(element)
}

public inline fun <K, V> Map<out K, V>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<K, V>) -> Unit): Unit {
    for (element in this) action(element)
}

public inline fun <T> Iterator<T>.forEach(operation: (T) -> Unit): Unit {
    for (element in this) operation(element)
}
```

So really they're all wrappers for a [basic `for` loop](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#for-loops), which as the documentation says, *iterates through anything that provides an iterator*. Your examples are all basically the same thing that's happening, just jumping in at various points in the *forEach -> basic for loop -> get an iterator* process.

The only part that's different is when you call `entries`, which returns a `Set` holding the key/value `Entry` pairs - so you're iterating over that, rather than the `Map` itself. But wait, what *does* happen if you call `iterator()` on a `Map`?

```
public inline operator fun <K, V> Map<out K, V>.iterator(): Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> = entries.iterator()
```

It uses `entries` itself! So yeah they're all the same thing

---

Really I think it comes down to this

- no need to call `iterator()` on anything unless you know you need one for some reason, like you're going to be calling `hasNext()` on it or whatever
- `forEach` fits with Kotlin's more declarative style, can be chained, and automatically passes in variables instead of you having to declare them
- sometimes a basic `for` loop is more readable for what you're doing though, especially if you're modifying some kind of `result` variable (which is more comparable to a `fold` than a `forEach` but anyway
- accessing `entries` on a `Map` means you're being explicit about what you're working with when you chain a `forEach` onto it, similar to how you can specify `keys` or `values` and only work with those. It's the same as just calling `forEach` on the map itself, but it's clearer

Comment: Thank you very much! This was very detailed and helpful :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the remove() function of the iterator to remove the item of map.

```
fun main() {
    val map = mutableMapOf("user1" to 29, "user2" to 25, "user3" to 26)
    val iterator = map.entries.iterator()
    println("Before iteration: $map")
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        val (key, value) = iterator.next()
        if (key == "user1") {
            iterator.remove()
        }

    }
    println("After iteration: $map")
}
```

It'll prints:

```
Before iteration: {user1=29, user2=25, user3=26}
After iteration: {user2=25, user3=26}
```